# Proving a continuous homomorphism from $(\mathbb{R}^2,+)$ to $(\mathbb{R}, +)$ is a linear transformation.

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory, linear-transformations, group-homomorphism

Let $\phi$ be a continuous homomorphism from from the group $(\mathbb{R}^2,+)$ to  the group $(\mathbb{R}, +)$. The, how could one prove that $\phi$ is also a linear transformation?

Given that $\phi$ is a homomorphism, we know that $\phi(x+y) = \phi(x) + \phi(y)$, so, one of the criteria for being a linear transformation is met.

What's left to prove is that $\phi(ax) =a\phi(x)$ (for $a\in \mathbb{R}$). Obviously $a\phi$ is also continuous for all $a\in \mathbb{R}$ and it's also obvious that any linear transformation from $\mathbb{R}^2$ to $\mathbb{R}$ is a continuous homomorphism. So, how could I prove that last step? Using the fact that $\lim_{x\to x_0} \phi(x) = \phi(x_0)$? (I've tried that and couldn't get anywhere.)

Comment: Try to prove equality $\phi(ax)=a\phi(x)$ for $a\in\mathbb{Z}$ first; then prove the equality for $a\in\mathbb{Q}$ and then apply your idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Let $(e_1,e_2)$ be a basis of $\mathbb{R}^2$, show that:

Let $n,m, p,q$ integers $f(ne_1+me_2)=nf(e_1)+mf(e_2)$

$f({1\over q}e_1)={1\over q}f(e_1)$,

$f({p\over q}e_1+{m\over n}e_2)={p\over q}f(e_1)+{m\over n}f(e_2)$ use continuity to show that $f(xe_1+ye_2)=xf(e_1)+yf(e_2)$.

Comment: Is the first statement true if $f$ is a homomorphism?

Comment: Yes, $n,m$ are integers

Comment: Why can I assume it's true for integers and not all reals?

Comment: $f(nx)=f(x+...+x)=f(x)+...+f(x)=nf(x)$

Comment: Thanks for being amazing!